# Is there an alternating series in which the sum is also one of the terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The geometric series 1/2 - 1/4 + 1/8 - 1/16 + ... sums to 1/3.
But 1/3 is not one of the terms that appears in the series.
Indeed, in general one would not expect the sum to appear as one of the terms.

I am curious, is there a natural example, or any example, of an alternating series in which the sum of the series also appears as one of the terms?

Comment: "Any example" Sure, we have that $$\frac13-\frac13+\frac12-\frac14+\frac18-\frac1{16}+\cdots$$sums to $\frac13$. It is indeed more interesting to ask about more "natural" occurrences, whatever that means.

Comment: By "natural", I mean a series with a closed-form summation expression such as the sum of the terms (-1)^(n+1)*1/2^n for all n from 1 to infinity, which is the natural mathematical expression for the series 1/2 - 1/4 + 1/8 - 1/16 + ... . One can artificially add terms, such as in your example, but these artificially added terms do not fit the form of the other terms, which are the alternating reciprocals of the powers of 2.

Comment: It is unclear what exact restrictions you are placing on the types of series you are interested in.  Yes, obviously it doesn't work for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{2})^n$... but that is just one very hyper specific example out of infinitely many.  Are you considering only geometric series?  Are you considering any series whose summands have an "easy" closed form expression?  How do you define "easy closed form expression"?  What makes one "easy" while another "not easy"?  What is the cutoff point in such a thing?

Comment: Consider $1 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}-\dots$  This has an "easy" closed representation for the terms...

Comment: Ok, but in your last example the “alternating” terms after the first term cancel each other out trivially. So I’m looking for a non-trivial example.

Answer (score 2):

$$1 = \cos 2\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ whose first term is $1$.

Comment: Thank you, very nice. Of course one could be argumentative and claim this example is "trivial" too, since cos(2*pi) = cos(0), and the terms of the Taylor series expansion at x=0 after the first term 1 are all 0. But in fact without knowing all these fundamental mathematical facts, it is by no means obvious that -(2*pi)^2/2! + (2*pi)^4/4! - (2*pi)^6/6! + (2*pi)^8/8! - ... sums to 0 ! So I consider this a very elegant example indeed. I observe that you chose cosine rather than sine for your example, since for sine only the trivial example of sin(0) satisfies the condition my question specified.

Comment: I will share with you the motivation for my question: I have found an alternating series expression whose limit is Euler's constant (gamma) as n approaches infinity, based on Vacca's series of 1910, in which every rational number (yes, *every* rational number) will appear as a term in the series expression for infinitely many values of n. Thus, if Euler's constant is rational, then the constant itself would appear as a term in the series whose sum approaches the constant itself.

Comment: The Taylor series for $\cos 0$ is trivial. But it defies any sensible meaning of the word to claim that the Taylor series for $\cos 2\pi$ is trivial. It is in fact a very non-trivial task to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ is periodic at all, much less with period $2\pi$ without having the advance knowledge of where it comes from. Indeed the most sensible way to prove it is effectively to use the differential equation it solves to prove that it is $\cos x$.

Comment: By the way, this example generalizes to a multitude of others. Take any analytic function $f$ with a radius of convergence $\ge 1$ about $x = 0$ and which has a root in that radius of convergence. Because the radius of convergence is $\ge 1$, the coefficients have to approach $0$, which means they are eventually inside the image of $f$. Then choose any coefficient $c$ small enough to be inside, and there is some $x_c$ such that $f(x_c) = c$. The Taylor series for $f(x_c)$ is another example.